# Can somebody explain how to add hadronic interaction in human phantom example of Geant4?

Tags: computational-physics, software, hadron-dynamics

I want to include hadronic interaction in human phantom example of Geant4. There is a header file G4HadronicInteraction.hh and a C++ file G4HadronicInteraction.cc and a file named G4HadronicInteraction.cc.o in Geant4. Suppose I just include G4HadronicInteraction.hh in phantom.cc file of human phantom, will it directly include everything from hadronic interaction? Or do I need to add something more in main phantom.cc file. By just adding the header file while building I don't see the .cc.o file so I think it means it is not included.

Please see the example at - https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/Geant4/AdvancedExamplesHumanPhantom

phantom.cc can be found at  -
https://gitlab.cern.ch/geant4/geant4/tree/master/examples/advanced/human_phantom

Comment: All of the interactions in Geant4 are set in the physics list.  Most of the standard physics lists already include G4HadronicInteraction, if memory serves - which are you using?

Comment: To me it look more like a programming (C++) question than a physics one.

Comment: While @stafusa is correct that this seems like programming question, my experience is that Geant4 is specialized enough that any experts are more likely to find it here on Physics than elsewhere.

Comment: That's a valid point, @rob, especially as he did already post in their forum, with no answer so far: http://hypernews.slac.stanford.edu/HyperNews/geant4/get/hadronprocess/1615.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about software not physcis

Comment: I suggest to re-ask your question on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @Murray, are you asking the which version of Geant4 I'm using, then its 4.10.3. Please correct me if I didn't get the question.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I copied the G4HadronicInteraction.cc file to the directory from where phantom.cc file is calling every other file which are being used in the code, then while building I could see the G4HadronicInteraction.cc.o file, but I don't understand if it is included in the code. What I think, I should add couple of lines in phantom.cc file to access classes of G4HadronicInteraction.hh file to the phantom.cc. I am trying to do that.

Comment: I think you may have a better topic match on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com .